# Why are principal crossed homomorphisms coboundaries?

Tags: soft-question, homology-cohomology, intuition, group-cohomology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Low-dimensional_cohomology_groups) (and to many other sources):

> The first cohomology group is the quotient of the so-called crossed
>   homomorphisms, i.e. maps (of sets) $f : G \to M$ satisfying
>   $f(ab)=f(a)+af(b)$ for all $a$, $b$ in G, modulo the so-called
>   principal crossed homomorphisms, i.e. maps $f : G \to M$ given by
>   $f(a) = am−m$ for some fixed $m\in M$.

Coboundaries are generally such cocycles which "doesn't matter", that is, adding them to a cocycle doesn't change some property of the cocycle. For example, in group cohomology, 2-coboundaries doesn't change the group extension defined by a 2-cocycle (see [here](https://books.google.hu/books?id=CHadhWO4DWYC&pg=PA223&dq=%22an+extension+of+G+by+A+is+uniquely+determined+by+the+structure+of+A+as+a+G-module+and+an+element+of+H2%7BG,+A)%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiay8quiMLgAhWSiIsKHbYPBQ8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22an%20extension%20of%20G%20by%20A%20is%20uniquely%20determined%20by%20the%20structure%20of%20A%20as%20a%20G-module%20and%20an%20element%20of%20H2%7BG%2C%20A)%22&f=false)).

**My question**: what is the property of a crossed homomorphism that remains unchanged by adding a principal crossed homomorphism to it?

**Edit**

The closest to my wish is [May](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1c6c/eb0b470201f452b7afbc9caab8760870fae0.pdf)'s Proposition 4.3:

> **Proposition 4.3.** The groups $Z^1(G;M)$ and $Aut(G;M)$ are isomorphic, and the isomorphism restricts to an isomorphism
>   $B^1(G;M)\cong Inn(G;M)$. Therefore $H^1(G;M)\cong Out(G;M)$.

Here $Out(G;M):=Aut(G;M)/Inn(G;M)$, and $Aut(G;M)$ is the automorphisms group of the canonical split extension of $M$ by $G$, and $Inn(G;M)$ is the inner automorphism group of it, that is the group of conjugations by the elements of $G$.

So, if we call two automorphisms *essentially the same*, if they differ by a conjugation, and we identify the crossed homomorphisms with $Aut(G;M)$ and the principal crossed homomorphisms to $Inn(G;M)$, then we can say that an a principal crossed homomorphism *essentially* doesn't change the crossed homomorphism. But this seems a bit far-fetched to me.

Comment: You say it seems far-fetched, but just note that higher (co)homology groups are always harder to interpret than the lower dimensional ones